# Red light only when plugging Pi2 into AV-Receiver via HDMI, TV works

Tags: pi-2, boot, boot-issues, board-leds

When I try to plug my Pi2 into my A/V receiver via HDMI and plug in my power cable afterwards, the red light lights up, afterwards the green light lights once and then nothing.

When I plug in the HDMI after powering up the Pi, the Pi boots and gives a (low-res) image on HDMI. The resolution of the image stays low, even if I put hdmi_mode=16 in the config.txt. hdmi_group=1 and hdmi_mode=16 only put it into widescreen.

However if I plug the Pi directly into my TV, everything works fine!

I tried all of these HDMI options so far:

```
hdmi_safe=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
config_hdmi_boost=7 (I tried 4-7)
```

I don't know what else I could do, maybe I am missing something?

I tried it with 2 different SD Cards, one running OpenElec and one running normal Raspbian, with the same results on both cards/OSes :/

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `hdmi_safe=1` and your group/mode settings are contradictions, please see [the documentation](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi_safe).  I don't think this necessarily causes a problem, I believe the latter options will override the former, but it does not seem like a good idea if you are trying to fine tune/debug your issue.

Comment: Yeah I might have not stated that good enough, I tested hdmi_safe=1 independently from group/mode

Comment: What is this A/V receiver? Is its HDMI port really an input?

Comment: Denon AVR-X500, yes ofcourse it is an input (I also tried 3 different inputs with the same result everywhere)

Comment: I felt a little stupid after asking ;)

Comment: Red light is normally a sign of a bad power supply, can your please try using something with a 1.2 amp  or higher

Comment: Red light actually is a sign, that the power supply works (it turns off when the power supply is too lowpowered or doesn't work at all), I'm also using a 2.1A power supply

Comment: Have you try a different hdmi cable and or switching ends. I know its sounds silly but it does fix a lot of hdmi issue